# SAML + SOA architecture design

Tags: soa, saml-2.0

I am trying to implement the SSO using SAML 2.0 in our application using SOA architecture.

[image: SSO design diagram] Here is a diagram representing the SSO design in my application.

I need to know if I am moving in right direction in regards to the flow between the identity provider, back end and, and front end part of my application or if there is something I need to improve.

The front end part of my application is in Angular JS and back end is just providing REST services.